# woocommerce - custom field in order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the need to have a custom field in the admin 'edit order' screen of woocommerce.

This field is admin only and does not need to display on the customer order process.

The business case is that the person processing the orders clicks in to the edit order screen for each order and assigns a custom ID (these are random serial numbers on our products) from a drop down list preferably.
The drop down list will be populated from a database of unassigned ID's - (this is a sql database we already use for our main web app)

My question is, is a custom field in the 'edit order' screen the place to perform this assignment? 
the alternative is to write a small .net application and assign the Id's there but I would like to keep the order processing to just woocommerce.

If it is possible what hooks should i look in to.

thank you

Answer (score -1):

If your good with PHP and MySQL, you can write your own filters and hooks for the wordpress backend. It's just like writing app's except everything will be pointed to the backend, woocommerce side.

You can read more about the filters and hooks for Wordpress:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API

You can either write your own plugins or add your functions etc. to your theme's function.php files.

Answer (score -1):

Use Woocommerce Custom Admin Order Field Plugin by WooThemes